# Turning dataframe into stacked percentage bar plot

Tags: r

I am trying to convert the following dataframe into a percentage stacked bar plot. the dataframe (df) looks like this:

[image]

I want to have 2 bars, one for before and one for after with each stacked bar being accepted, rejected and cancelled.

Comment: Hi. Couple of comments/questions: 1. please don't share data as images. Use `dput(df)` to produce a shareable format of your data. 2. Where does the "accepted, rejected, and cancelled" info coming from? There's nothing like that in your data. 3. What about the months? Do they play into the bar chart in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a generalized way to get a percentage stacked bar chart using your data (generatlized because I'm not sure what exactly you're asking for as noted in my comment above):

```
require(tidyverse)
df %>% gather("var", "val", before, after) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x=var, y=val,fill=type)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="fill")
```

This gives you this - is that what you're looking for?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

IMHO, the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55437468/3817004) can be improved to better reflect the structure of OP's data

1. by preserving the order of columns `before` and `after` and
2. by preserving the given order of rows.

To achieve this, there are two options:

- Either turn the categorial variables into factors with levels in the desired order
- or specify the desired order when plotting using `scale_discrete()`.

The code below uses both techniques:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(type = forcats::fct_inorder(type)) %>%   # preserve row order
  gather("var", "share", before, after) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = var, y = share, fill = type)) +
  geom_col(position = "fill") +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("before", "after"), name = NULL) +   # specify column order
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

to produce a graphical equivalent of OP's data:

[image]

Furthermore, `geom_col()` is used as a shortcut for  `geom_bar(stat = "identity")` and the y axis is labelled appropriately.

#### Data

As the OP has not provided a reproducible dataset but posted an image of the data, I have used an on-line OCR service to convert the screenshot into text. (For the sake of completeness: If have searched for "online ocr" and picked randomly https://www.newocr.com/ which happens to produce the desired result at first instance).

Then, the OCR result was copied into the code snippet below:

```
df <- readr::read_table2(
"type before after
january 297 237
february 182 67
march 234 34
april 55 117")
```